# Practical question about SOLID programming practises

Tags: solid-principles, dependency-inversion

A practical question about Dependency Inversion Principle:

We want to build our systems in many libraries or DLLs.

If the components or classes of a lower level library should depend upon an abstraction, be it an Iinterface or pure abstract class and the callee executable or higher-level library should also depend upon that abstraction rather than the concrete class then into which library should the abstraction be compiled?

Yes of course, the concrete class is wired and provided by a factory...

Logically, it belongs in the executable or higher level library but perhaps for practical purposes it should be compiled into the lower level library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most flexible (modular) approach is to compile the abstraction into its own binary file (library). This allows anyone to use and/or extend the abstraction without inheriting any implementation details. Ideally, this means without inheriting any transitive dependencies.

If the abstraction will only be consumed by one client, you may safely compile it along with its consumer, to reduce the amount of binary files. This will keep the concrete implementation(s) decoupled from the client.

The one thing you should not do is compile the abstraction along with any of its implementations. That would couple every client to the implementation code as well as its transitive dependencies.

Comment: Super idea, thanks! Got the point about not compiling the abstraction into the same library as the implementation - just felt wrong but you clarified the reason for me. Also to build the factories which create boundary objects (which wire up the concrete objects by injection) into their own library. Easier to change the concrete injected objects without recompiling the application that way.